# Interval data question type survey problem (statistical treatment)

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

We conduct a research recently and we are now in the part of applying such statistical treatment. However, we are currently having a problem wherein what statistical treatment on the data would we use. The question is how much is your budget or average amount spent in phones? 
less than 60 dollars
60-120 dollars
121-180 dollars
181-240 dollars 
241-300 dollars
301 and above dollars

Can we still use Frequency Distribution Table even though our last data inputted was and above dollars?

Answer (score 0):

It depends (a) on what use you want to make of the data, and (b) on what
proportion of of the data are below \$60 or above \$301.

For example, if you want the *mean* amount spent on phones then
you could use $m_i$ for interval midpoints, $f_i$ for interval frequencies
and get the mean as $\frac{\sum_i m_if_i}{\sum_i f_i}.$ If frequencies
for the open-ended first and last intervals are insignificantly small,
you might ignore those intervals. If you need to include them, perhaps
make $m_1 = 30$ and $m_6 = 330.$

If you want to find the *median* amount, you could find the interval
in which the median lies, and interpolate within the interval to get
an approximate value for the median of the sample.

However, if this is *your* research, it might be possible to retrieve
the original data used to make the summary table.